# Function for a simple open file/save file dialog with PyQT

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am now learning pyQT and I would like to do something that is presumably not difficult, but for which I could not find any satisfactory answer on the internet : Create a function using pyQT5 that just opens the standard file dialog of Windows or Ubuntu from iPython and returns the filepath (and filename).

My first attempts from tutorials found online ( https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qfiledialog_widget.htm ) were not successful. It looks something like:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTextEdit, 
    QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


def test_dialog():
    dlg = QFileDialog()
    dlg.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile)
    if dlg.exec_():
        filenames = dlg.selectedFiles()
        return filenames


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_dialog()
```

I use the latest versions of anaconda distribution with Python 3.7.3 and pyQT 5.9.2 .

Comment: change `if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_dialog()` to `if __name__ == '__main__':
 app = QApplication.instance()
 if app is None: app = QApplication([])
 print(test_dialog())`

Comment: Thanks. But now I have another problem: When I hit «cancel» on the dialog, the instance stays on in the background and I cannot open another dialog without restarting ipython first. How can I close the dialog ?

Comment: I recommend you read: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/eventloops.html#integrating-with-gui-event-loops , Using the above I get the following https://i.imgur.com/ptdh6uT.png

Comment: Strange … but I solved my problem addind `QTimer.singleShot(100, app.quit)`. One last question if I may: if I add `dlg.setFilter("Text files (*.txt)")`, I get the error message TypeError: setFilter(self, Union[QDir.Filters, QDir.Filter]): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'.

Comment: Using QTimer.singleShot(..., app.quit) is a solution but not the right solution. On the other hand I recommend you read the docs before implementing something: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html,

Comment: [cont.] QFileDialog has a [setFilter()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setFilter) method that receives the [QDir::Filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Filter-enum) that allows a filter to be made in what is observed in the dialog eg QDir::Files will only allow files to be selected, or QDir::Dirs will only choose directories .

Comment: [cont.] Instead you must use [setNameFilter()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setNameFilter): `dlg.setNameFilter("Text files (*.txt)")`